# Blazor Identity - user available in razor HTML, not in @code

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

This is really weird. In the html part of a razor page (Blazor server using ASP.NET Identity) I can use the following:

```
<div class="text-center">@context.User.Identity?.Name</div>
```

But in the @code I cannot call:

```
var name = context.User.Identity?.Name;
```

Why?

And yes I do have CascadingAuthenticationState in App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <h1>Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.</h1>
                    <p>You may want to try logging in (as someone with the necessary authorization).</p>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Here's an example. It's longer than I prefer but what matters is the `@context.User.Identity?.Name` - which works

```
@*
    copyright (C) 2023 by David Thielen. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
    This code is confidential and is only to be viewed and/or used by authorized individuals & entities.
*@

@using System.Drawing

@inject Services.TokenProvider TokenProvider

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <nav>
            <DxMenu Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal"
                    DropDownActionMode="MenuDropDownActionMode.Click"
                    DisplayMode="MenuDisplayMode.Desktop"
                    CollapseItemsToHamburgerMenu="true"
                    CollapseItemToIconMode="MenuCollapseItemToIconMode.All">
                <Items>
                    <DxMenuItem CssClass="notoggle" Position="ItemPosition.Start">
                        <Template Context="menuContext">
                            <div id="drop-down-target" style="margin: 10px" class="menu-icon" @onclick="() => IsOpen = !IsOpen">
                                <img src="@_base64Image" class="resizable-image circled s-16 menu-icon" alt="User Avatar placeholder" />
                            </div>
                            <DxDropDown @bind-IsOpen="@IsOpen" Width="200" PositionTarget="#drop-down-target"
                                        PositionMode="DropDownPositionMode.Bottom" FooterVisible="true" Context="popupContext">
                                <BodyTextTemplate Context="bodyContext">
                                    <div class="w-100 user-profile ">
                                        <div class="flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="logo-container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                                <img src="@_base64Image" class="resizable-image circled s-64" alt="User Avatar placeholder" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="user-name-container bm-3 mb-2">
                                                <div class="text-center">@context.User.Identity?.Name</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center log-off-btn">
                                                <a href="/profile">View profile</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </BodyTextTemplate>
                                <FooterTextTemplate>
                                    <form action="/identity/account/logout" method="post">
                                        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" type="submit">
                                            <span class="oi oi-account-logout" aria-hidden="true"></span> Log out (@context.User.Identity?.Name)
                                        </button>
                                        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"
                                               value="@TokenProvider.XsrfToken">
                                    </form>
                                </FooterTextTemplate>
                            </DxDropDown>
                        </Template>
                    </DxMenuItem>
                    <DxMenuItem Text="Dashboard" IconCssClass="oi oi-spreadsheet" NavigateUrl="/user/dashboard" />
                    <DxMenuItem Text="Search Events" IconCssClass="oi oi-magnifying-glass" NavigateUrl="/search" />
                    <DxMenuItem Text="History" IconCssClass="oi oi-list" NavigateUrl="/history" />
                    <DxMenuItem Text="Pending" IconCssClass="oi oi-inbox" NavigateUrl="/pending" />
                    <DxMenuItem CssClass="no-background" Text="3 days to the election" Position="ItemPosition.End" />
                </Items>
            </DxMenu>
        </nav>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <nav>
            <DxMenu Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal"
                    DropDownActionMode="MenuDropDownActionMode.Click"
                    DisplayMode="MenuDisplayMode.Desktop"
                    CollapseItemsToHamburgerMenu="true"
                    CollapseItemToIconMode="MenuCollapseItemToIconMode.All">
                <Items>
                    <DxMenuItem Text="Home" IconCssClass="oi oi-home" NavigateUrl="/" />
                    <DxMenuItem Text="Login" IconCssClass="oi oi-account-login" NavigateUrl="/identity/account/Login?ReturnUrl=/dashboard" />
                    <DxMenuItem Text="Register" IconCssClass="oi oi-document" NavigateUrl="/Account/Register" />
                    <DxMenuItem CssClass="no-background" Text="the election is in 3 days" Position="ItemPosition.End" />
                </Items>
            </DxMenu>
        </nav>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<!--
<p>image: <img src="@_base64Image" width="32" height="32" alt="User Avatar placeholder"/></p>
-->
@code {
    private bool IsOpen { get; set; } = false;
    private string _base64Image;

    private Bitmap Avatar
    {
        get
        {
            // will get this from DB
            return new Bitmap("wwwroot/images/DavidThielen.jpg");
        }
    }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _base64Image = Avatar.ConvertToBase64();

        // This will NOT compile
        var name = context.User.Identity?.Name;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

But in the @code part context is not recognized.

Comment: Can you include the method surrounding the code - context is important

Comment: That's great, but you don't have anything in the `@code` section that would fail. To get access to the `User` in `@code` you would need to [Expose the authentication state as a cascading parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#expose-the-authentication-state-as-a-cascading-parameter)

Comment: @MisterMagoo Access issue added to code part.